# Separation of variables pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following equation:

$$u_{tt}= u_{xx} - 3 u_t, \ \  \ \ t>0 , x \in (0, \pi ) $$

$$u(0, x) = f(x), \ \ \  x \in [0, \pi] $$

$$u(t,0)= u(t, \pi ) = 0, \ \ \ \  t>0 $$

$u(t,x) = T(t)X(x)$

We get $$\frac{T''(t) + 3T'(t)}{T(t)} = \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)} = - \lambda $$

I've already excluded the cases when $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda <0$, then we get $u=0$

When $\lambda >0$, we have $X(x) = B_n \sin (nx)$.

And $T''(t) + 3 T'(t) + \lambda T(t) = 0$

Could you tell me what $T$ looks like?

I know that we need to compute roots of this equation: $w^2 + 3w + \lambda = 0$, $w = \pm \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{9-4 \lambda} + \frac{3}{2}$, but $9 - 4 \lambda$ could be negative. Is there a mistake somewhere?

Could you help?

Comment: looks like a damped harmonic oscillator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I answer, just a small mistake: $w = \frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{9-4\lambda} - \frac{3}{2}$ (**not** $+\frac{3}{2}$)

Yes, you have it right: you need further break into cases $9-4\lambda\geq0$ and $9-4\lambda<0$ (one of them doesn't quite make physical sense).

If $9-4\lambda<0$, then denoting $\sqrt{9-4\lambda}/2$ as $Di$ (i.e.\ $D=\sqrt{9-4\lambda}/2$), we have two solutions $e^{\pm Dix}e^{-3/2x} = e^{-3/2x}(\cos(Dx)\pm i \sin(Dx))$.
Well, linear combinations of the solutions are also solutions, so the two **real** solutions are $e^{-3/2x}\cos(Dx)$ and $e^{-3/2x}\sin(Dx)$ (now this seems really like a dampened oscillator no?)

Comment: I'm sorry, there should always be $3$

Comment: Has been edited.

Comment: So, while looking for $X(x)$ I've established that $\lambda = n^2, n \in N$, so if $9- 4 \lambda>0$ we would only have $n=1,2$ and so we assume that it is $>0$, so we assume that $n=3,4,5,...$ and while creating the Fourier series we also take a sum from $3$ to infinity. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right.

Comment: Great, thank you. I'll try to finish the solution now. Ups, it should be n=2,3,...

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake: it should be
$$\frac{T''+\color{red}{2}T'}{T}.$$
This will make the computations easier, but there is no problem in getting complex roots. A root $a+i\,b$ gives solutions $e^{at}\cos(b\,t)$ and $e^{at}\sin(b\,t)$.